# How to read a int array from a text file in python?

Tags: python, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a text file like this:

```
0 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

And i would like to get a 2D array like this:

```
[[0,0,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,0,1],
[0,1,0]]
```

I have tried:

```
with open("Input_Data.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    input_data = [line.split() for line in txt_file]
print(input_data)
```

But it returns:

```
[['0', '0', '1'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '0']]
```

How could I get an array of int instead of string please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line of code:

```py
input_data = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in txt_file]
```

You got strings, but you wanted integers so you have to parse each string into an integer.

`map` will apply the function given as first argument to all elements in the second argument, and return an iterator. Then you consume that iterator by using `list` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Input_Data.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    input_data = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in txt_file]
print(input_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete answers, I add `loadtxt` function of `numpy` lib. It's very simple, output is a `ndarray`:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.loadtxt("Input_Data.txt", dtype="uint8", delimiter=' ')
```

You can specify data type, default is `float`.